# Касание двух или более элементов

Tags: android, multi-touch

Возвращаюсь к старому вопросу, но в данный момент суть проблемы немного глубже.
Есть 8 кнопок, они играют 8 звуков (1 кнопка играет 1 звук), пользователь должен иметь возможность интенсивно нажимать их, а значит, нужно реализовать возможность аналогичную мультитачу, но все же есть различия: когда пользователь **зажал** одну из кнопок, он должен мочь **нажать любую** из оставшихся 7, чтобы та проиграла звук (мультитач такого делать не позволяет, если я зажал кнопку 1, кнопка 2 не отреагирует), аналогично с 2 зажатыми кнопками при нажатии 3-ей, примеров с 3-мя зажатыми я не видел. Пара примеров, где я это видел, для наглядности:

- https://market.android.com/details?id=com.bti.myDrums&feature=search_result
- https://market.android.com/details?id=com.phellax.drum&feature=search_result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Лично я, когда было надо, не мудрил особо и банально перекрыл
    View.onTouchEvent(MotionEvent)
а далее ручками. Там не так сложно в целом.

- Создать у себя что-то вроде массива самописных объектов-кнопок, каждый из которых хранит некий Rectangle и текущее состояние (нажата/отжата).
- Потом аккуратно разобрать MotionEvent по пальчикам и по этим самым Rectangle, что куда попало.
- Зафиксировать в поле объекта-кнопки нажатие/отжатие.
- Разослать подписчику "кнопки" сообщения нажатия/отжатия при смене состояния.
- Заинвалидировать в View соответствующий Rectangle при смене состояния.
- Получить onDraw. Отрисовать картинки соответствующие нажатым и отжатым кнопкам.

Comment: Примерно так и сделал.